WinForm - pixel font not rendering correctly
I'm trying to use a pixel style font to write text on a bitmap in WinForm.
The font I'm using is this: https://font.download/font/pocket-pixel.
I want the text to be very small (6pt) and pixel perfect, without antialiasing, but when drawing text on a bitmap, it does not match the font.
When using the font in an image editing software (in my case Paint.NET), I set the size to 6 pt, and the result is perfect.
When I go ahead and use the same font to draw text on a bitmap in WinFrom, the result is both small and messed up, even at higher font sizes.
I have both a template bitmap and the font file embedded as resources.
public class Class1 
{
    private static PrivateFontCollection fonts = new PrivateFontCollection();

    static FontFamily LoadFontResource(byte[] fontData)
    {
        IntPtr fontPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontData.Length);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, fontPtr, fontData.Length);
        uint dummy = 0;
        fonts.AddMemoryFont(fontPtr, fontData.Length);
        AddFontMemResourceEx(fontPtr, (uint)fontData.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref dummy);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontPtr);
    
        return fonts.Families.Last();
    }

    public Bitmap GetBitmap()
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(Resources.template);
    
        FontFamily PocketPixel_FontFamily = LoadFontResource(Resources.pokemon_pixel_font);
        Font PocketPixel_Font = new Font(PocketPixel_FontFamily, 12, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);    
        
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            Brush brush = Brushes.Black;
            StringFormat format = new StringFormat
            {
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, // Justify center
                LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
            };
        
            // Disable anti-aliasing
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.None;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
            
            graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
            graphics.PageScale = 1f;
            
            // Draw text
            RectangleF area = new RectangleF(20, 145, 100, 10);
            graphics.DrawString("1234567890", PocketPixel_Font, brush, area, format);
        }
        
        return bmp;
    
    }

    public SavePng()
    {
        var bmp = GetBitmap();
        bmp.Save("WhyYouNoWork.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}

As you see, I tried changing several properties of the Graphics object or the Font object itself to get to the desired result, but with no luck.

Keep only graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;, comment out the rest of the Graphics settings. Make sure the Rectangle you specify is large enough, otherwise you may mess up the rendering (e.g., you have a Font of 12 pixels in height, the height of the rectangle is 10 pixels). You can remove the AddFontMemResourceEx() call and Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() -- Make a test like this, see how it goes -- You should specify what Resources.template maps to -- What does Please upvote for pictures mean?

I just found out that I was importing the wrong font:
FontFamily PocketPixel_FontFamily = LoadFontResource(Resources.pokemon_pixel_font);

instead of importing the actual "Pocket Pixel Font".
